# Do any languages mention the top limit of a range first?

Tags: syntax, list-of-languages, numbers

In many languages we usually say "between min and max" (e.g., grades "between 1 and 10").

Are there any languages where the reverse construction ("between max and min", e.g. grades "between 10 and 1") is used?

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE! I have edited your question to add some tags and an example, as well as clarify the title and change the formatting (backticks (` ` `) are used for code; they are read character-by-character by some screen readers so they are not suitable here). If you feel like I changed too much, you can always rollback. As a new user, please take the [tour] to learn more about our model. I hope you enjoy the site!

Comment: What sorts of constructions are you willing to consider? I've been searching high and low for examples... :)

Comment: As a place for someone else to research or remember, I have heard that Native Americans (at least one group in the Midwest) say things like "I like 3 or 2 flavors of ice cream" instead of "2 or 3".  This may be formalized in those languages

Comment: There's an `UP/DOWN` metaphor theme involved here, possibly in connection with a `PATH` metaphor theme.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In German, I am aware of two instances where the "reverse" order is used:

1) The weather forecast of the newscast "Tagesschau" (and quite possibly many other weather forecasts, but not all) always states the range of lowest expected temperatures with the higest number first. From [today's 8pm broadcast](https://youtu.be/V2jB49t6M34?t=870):

> In der Nacht 19 bis 12 Grad; am Tag 18 Grad im südwestlichen Bergland, 27 in der Niederlausitz.

Translation:

> At night, 19 to 12 degrees [celsius]; during the day, 18 degrees in the southwestern uplands, 27 degrees in Lower Lusatia.

I is used very consistently. Here are the archived broadcasts of the last few days.:

- https://youtu.be/kADSW8lqb60?t=882
- https://youtu.be/4kRKGXeYigg?t=972
- https://youtu.be/t8JOLMGEMSw?t=903
- https://youtu.be/yBssC2K_LmY?t=886
- https://youtu.be/6oZLJJC2hts?t=952

If you understand a little bit of German, you can listen out for the numbers and for the word "Grad" (degrees).

Usage of this ordering goes back a long way. See for example [this 1983 recording](https://youtu.be/nMyyaK3Ad2w?t=808):

> Tiefsttemperaturen 5 bis 1, Tageshöchsttemperaturen 7[!] bis 12 Grad

*yes, he says 7, even though the thermometer graphic displays 9*

However, these even older recordings use "standard ordering":

[December 30, 1973](https://youtu.be/yu5naTZ9B18?t=855)

> Im Norden Tiefsttemperaturen 1 bis 5 Grad, Tageshöchsttemperaturen 4 bis 7 [cut off]

[July 30, 1979](https://youtu.be/_8Z8djBzy1Q?t=848)

> Tiefsttemperaturen in der Nacht 11 bis 15 Grad, Tageshöchsttemperaturen 20 bis 25 Grad, nur im Norden etwas weniger.

2) Some cities (particularly those with [inconsistent numbering schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_numbering#Germany)) add house number range information to all or some of their street name signs. The house number that is closest to the location of the sign is stated first, followed by the last house number before the next (major) intersection, which often results in the larger number coming first. [This Berlin-style sign](https://www.schilder-versand.com/verkehrsschilder/strassenschilder/18643/Berliner-Hausnummerneinschuebe) shows for example "56 – 48".

Comment: Funny, I never noticed that. Wonder why they do it this way.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I guess because at night the temperature normally goes down and not up. that's why we say from 19 to 12 degrees in the night. means: as the night goes on, it gets colder. (Again, only a **guess**)

Comment: If that's true, it's not really describing a range, it's describing a progression. I expect we'd say it similarly in English, "the temperature will drop from 70 to 60 during the night."

Comment: @sLw I think the 19 and 12 degrees are both minima, at different locations - not a progression at one location.

Comment: Related, forecasts in English are often given like "high of 19, low of 12".

Comment: For case 1), it is not a ‘normal range’. The direction is important, it’s saying ‘it goinge down to 5 degrees, or even 1 if you’re in the coldest spot’. In a way, it is a mirrored range, and the lower mirrored value, the one closer to normal is put first, followed by the greater value, farther away from normal.

And for case 2), this is common on the signs, but not a feature of the language.

Answer (score 9):

There are, presumably in all languages, situations where the top limit is mentioned first. For example, we may talk about "between 10 and 20 metres below sea level".

So this seems to be primarily a matter of which limit is felt 'closer' to the speaker (and that would be the limit that is mentioned first). Because we normally count up, the lower limit is more likely to be the first to be mentioned and would also be the default if not one of the limits is felt 'closer'.

Also in the example of grades "between 1 and 10", you could argue that 1 is the easiest to obtain and therefore 'closer' to the speaker (I would be interested to know whether Americans say "grades from F to A" or "from A to F", because that could falsify this claim).

Comment: In terms of grades of achievement for public examinations, in England (& Wales), the [Edexcel Mathematics GCSE specification](https://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/GCSE/mathematics/2015/specification-and-sample-assesment/gcse-maths-2015-specification.pdf) states: "The qualification will be graded and certificated on a nine-grade scale from 9 to 1 using the total mark across all three papers where 9 is the highest grade", and then for the _tiering_ states "Foundation tier: grades 1 to 5" and also "Higher tier: grades 4 to 9 (grade 3 allowed)".

Comment: @Michaelyus very interesting, thanks for that! I'm not a native speaker of English, but in Dutch this would be very unnatural. It would look like you're actively trying to stimulate a positive mindset or something like that.

Comment: While not really a question of "upper" and "lower" limits, exits on highways in the US are often numbered, and if you're travelling _toward_ the end of the highway where the exit numbers start, traffic reports for that direction will often say things like "congestion from (e.g.,) exit 31 to 15".

Comment: In “between 10 and 20 metres below sea level”, 20 metres is still the top limit, even if it’s further down below the surface. Of course there can always be some external factor that makes it relevant to specify the upper limit first, but as I understand the question, it is about giving ‘neutral’ ranges; for example, would any language naturally say, “We talked to each for about ten to five minutes” (instead of “five to ten minutes”)? I suspect the ‘proximity’ factor you mention is fairly universal and the answer is no, but I don’t know.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not sure from where you get that the question is about 'neutral' ranges. But yes, the point of my answer was that it depends on perspective. Michaelyus' example shows that there can even be cases where both are possible, possibly depending on what you want to emphasise.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin :  We similarly have some dates backwards, as ‘Cleopatra (69–30 BCE)’.

Comment: @TobyBartels - Indeed; that's a better example than mine; it just never occurred to me.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it just justifies the English formulation. Referencing physical realities, like the fact that 20 meters below sea level is "lower" than 10, doesn't change the fact that 20 is more than 10, and thus it was mentioned last. Are there any languages that use a formulation like "between 20 and 10", regardless of unit?

Comment: @AlekStorm that really depends on how you read the question, which is underspecified. In my reading, this answers the question affirmatively because English satisfies the criteria. (But I would definitely agree that this answer was accepted too quickly and [this other answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/32106/17305) as well as some comments here give better examples.)

Comment: @TobyBartels Your data example is not "backwards", it is still "(birth -- death)".  Would you argue that for time periods like "20 BCE - 30AD"  and "30 BCE - 20 AD" one of them should be written "backwards" compared with the other, because 30 is bigger than 20?

Comment: @alephzero the whole point of this post is that it depends on perspective.

Comment: @alephzero :  I am certainly not claiming that anything should be said differently.

Comment: German can falsify the grades claim. In Germany and Austria, grades go from 1 (A) to 6 (F), so 6 is the easiest to obtain. Yet if in a survey you are asked to grade something, the typical question is always ‘Vergeben Sie Schulnoten von 1 bis 6.’

Comment: @Jan the claim is that the speaker can use whatever is closest. In that system, it allows for either *1 bis 6* or *6 bis 1*: the first because 1 is closest to 0, the second because 6 is the easiest to obtain.

Comment: @Keelan I cannot remember encountering *6 bis 1* in the real world even once. (I even considered adding a star to it here). It is so overwhelmingly *1 bis 6* that I would probably have to read twice if I saw the opposite.

Comment: @Jan yes, the claim is underspecified.

Answer (score 4):

In Japanese, you often have this construct as well. An example is "100分の１is" one of 100 parts (lit: 100 parts and 1) for fractions.  You tend to bound problem as well when you are speaking in regard to mathematics.  I generally give the limits of equations before I discuss the points; however, that could just specific to the discipline of mathematics in Japanese.

Comment: I assume you mean 分 (bun), not 部.

Comment: @Nardog oops, yeah.  will update.  phone entry. :/

Comment: A fraction is not really a range, though - does this occur in ranges, too?

Comment: @Keelan 100以内の5.  5 bounded by 100.  When you describe limits in calculus, you'll bound it.  Sadly, my Japanese is mostly in a technical context.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether this should be an answer, since it's not about numerical ranges, but there are definitely certain idioms in English that seem to put the "greater" extreme first, such as:

- high and low (e.g., I've been searching high and low…)
- top to bottom (although, for some things, like written text in English, top to bottom could still be "lower" to "higher", just as "from the top" means "from the beginning")
- head to toe